# Point-free at top-level in Standard ML

Tags: sml, pointfree

The first and the second `flatMap` work well. Why doesn't the third one work?

```
fun flatMap f xs = List.concat(List.map f xs)
fun flatMap f = List.concat o List.map f
val flatMap = (fn mmp => List.concat o mmp) o List.map;
```

Comment: Because of a rule in the language specification called "value restriction": http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a rule called "value polymorphism" or the "value restriction". According to this rule, a value declaration can't create a polymorphic binding if the expression might be "expansive"; that is, a value declaration can only create a polymorphic binding if it conforms to a highly restricted grammar that ensures it can't create ref cells or exception names.

In your example, since `(fn mmp => List.concat o mmp) o List.map` calls the function `o`, it's not non-expansive; *you* know that `o` doesn't create ref cells or exception names, but the grammar can't distinguish that.

So the declaration `val flatMap = (fn mmp => List.concat o mmp) o List.map` is still allowed, but it can't create a polymorphic binding: it has to give `flatMap` a monomorphic type, such as `(int -> real list) -> int list -> real list`. (Note: not all implementations of Standard ML can infer the desired type in all contexts, so you may need to add an explicit type hint.)

This restriction exists to ensure that we don't implicitly cast from one type to another by writing to a ref cell using one type and reading from it using a different type, or by wrapping one type in a polymorphic exception constructor and unwrapping it using a different type. For example, the below programs are forbidden by the value restriction, but if they were allowed, each would create a variable named `garbage` of type `string` that is initialized from the *integer* `17`:

```
val refCell : 'a option ref =
  ref NONE

val () = refCell := SOME 17

val garbage : string =
  valOf (! refCell)
```

```
val (wrap : 'a -> exn, unwrap : exn -> 'a) =
  let
    exception EXN of 'a
  in
    (fn x => EXN x, fn EXN x => x)
  end

val garbage : string =
  unwrap (wrap 17)
```

For more information:

- ["ValueRestriction" in the MLton documentation](http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction)
- ["Value restriction" on the English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_restriction)
- ["Types and Type Checking" in SML/NJ's guide to converting programs from Standard ML '90 to Standard ML '97](https://www.smlnj.org/doc/Conversion/types.html). (Standard ML '90 had a different version of this rule, that was more permissive — it would have allowed your program — but considered "somewhat subtle" and in some cases "unpleasant", hence its replacement in Standard ML '97.)
- the following sections of [*The Definition of Standard ML (Revised)* (PDF)](https://smlfamily.github.io/sml97-defn.pdf):

  - §4.7 "Non-expansive Expressions", page 21, which defines which expressions are considered "non-expansive" (and can therefore be used in polymorphic value declarations).
  - §4.8 "Closure", pages 21–22, which defines the operation that makes a binding polymorphic; this operation enforces the value restriction by *preventing* the binding from becoming polymorphic if the expression might be expansive.
  - inference rule (15), page 26, which uses the aforementioned operation; see also the comment on page 27.
  - the comment on inference rule (20), page 27, which explains why the aforementioned operation is not applied to exception declarations. (Technically this is somewhat separate from the value restriction; but the value restriction would be useless without this.)
  - §G.4 "Value Polymorphism", pages 105–106, which discusses this change from Standard ML '90.